# How to loop multiple form input and assign into sql query in php?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter

```
public function add_employee($input)
{
    $key_array = null;
    $value_array = null;
    $bind_array = null;
    foreach ($input as $column => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            #$bind_array => ?, ?, ?;
            #$value_array => [$value1, $value2, $value3];
            #$key_array => column1, column2, column3;
        }
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ol_employee ($key_array) VALUES ($bind_array)";
    $this->db->query($sql, $value_array);
}
```

Refer to comment in the function, how to achieve that output?
the idea is, from the input POST i get which over 27 fields, i just want to fill in into the $sql query i prepared as you can see. I don't think writing each table column manually is a good way.

im using Codeigniter 4 php framework + postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the insight of Alex Granados, this is the query i use:

```
public function add_employee($input)
{
    foreach ($input as $column => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $data[$column] = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->db->table('ol_employee')->insert($data);
}
```

this will eliminate null field  and regardless how many field, still working good.
as long the input name field from form is same as db column. Else, need to do some changes on that.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

According to [CodeIgniter 4 documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/examples.html?highlight=database), you can do this inside your loop for each employee:

```
$data = [
    'title' => $title,
    'name'  => $name,
    'date'  => $date
];

$db->table('mytable')->insert($data);
```

Comment: it's not the question. i'm not into writing those column name 1 by 1, its over 27 fields. Looping the is the only way. but i dont hv idea how to append those things. thats all. please see the desire outcome im looking for in the function comment.

Comment: If you want an array with all the keys and another array with all the values you can take a look to `array_keys` and `array_values` PHP functions.

Comment: array_combine is the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and implode function first make array of key_array, value_array and bind_array then use implode() and use in sql like following

```
public function add_employee($input)
{
    $key_array = array();
    $value_array = array();
    $bind_array = array();
    foreach ($input as $column => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $bind_array[] = '?';
            $value_array[] = $value;
            $key_array[] = $column;
        }
    }

    $binds = implode(",",$bind_array);
    $keys = implode(",",$key_array);    
    $values = implode(",",$value_array);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ol_employee ($keys) VALUES ($binds)";
    $this->db->query($sql,$values);
}
```

Comment: looks like what im looking for.. will try first

Comment: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...title, password, privilege, mr_id, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,... ^

im also already fix your code on $value_array[] = $value; also $this->db->query($sql,[$values]);.. still having issue

Comment: can you send me sql query ? so i can check that what is issue